# highcharts line chart with same x value, how to handle click events

Tags: highcharts

I have a line chart that is used to show milestone events. So the xaxis is the date. If the data has more than one event on the same date, I offset the y value so that the point markers are stacked vertically. I don't want to make the y offset too big because that would make it hard to handle multiple markers on the same date. The markers also have a hover. Problem is that when I hover near a marker, only one marker's hover shows and I can only click on one marker.

See this jsfiddle with the label "Upgrade": http://jsfiddle.net/MichaelWitt/adun8km8/1/

You cannot click on this, but you can see the behavior on the hover as you cannot get the blue triangle to hover.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  "title": {
    "text": null
  },
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "chart": {
    "zoomType": "x",
    "type": "line",
    "plotBackgroundImage": null,
    "backgroundColor": "transparent",
    "height": 330,
    "borderWidth": 0,
    "top": 0,
    "marginTop": 0,
    "marginBottom": 150,
    "marginLeft": 120
  },
  "legend": {
    "enabled": false,
    "align": "left",
    "verticalAlign": "top",
    "layout": "vertical",
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0,
    "useHTML": false,
    "itemMarginTop": 4,
    "itemHoverStyle": {
      "color": "#3094d1",
      "font": "Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
      "fontSize": "10px",
      "fontWeight": "normal"
    },
    "itemStyle": {
      "color": "#404b56",
      "font": "Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
      "fontSize": "12px",
      "fontWeight": "normal"
    },
    "itemHiddenStyle": {
      "color": "#caced1",
      "font": "Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
      "fontSize": "12px",
      "fontWeight": "normal"
    }
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "type": "datetime",
    "lineWidth": 0,
    "lineColor": "#404b56",
    "tickColor": "#404b56",
    "tickInterval": 173520000,
    "gridLineColor": "#222222",
    "labels": {
      "style": {
        "font": "Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
        "fontSize": "10px",
        "fontWeight": "bold",
        "color": "#404b56",
        "zIndex": -100
      },
      "format": "{value:%b %d, %Y}"
    }
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "labels": {
      "enabled": true,
      "style": {
        "font": "Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
        "fontSize": "10px",
        "fontWeight": "bold",
        "color": "#404b56",
        "zIndex": -100
      },
      "y": 3
    },
    "gridLineColor": "#dddddd",
    "tickColor": "#dddddd",
    "title": {
      "text": null
    },
    "tickInterval": 1
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "series": {
      "marker": {
        "enabled": true,
        "radius": 8,
        "symbol": "triangle"
      },
      "cursor": "pointer",
      "events": {},
      "point": {
        "stickyTracking": false
      },
      "states": {
        "hover": {
          "enabled": true,
          "lineWidth": 0,
          "lineWidthPlus": 0
        }
      }
    },
    "line": {
      "lineWidth": 0,
      "stickyTracking": false
    }
  },
  "series": [{
    "name": "Upgrade",
    "data": [{
      "x": 1510203600000,
      "y": 0,
      "name": "Upgrade",
      "key": 158,
      "shortDesc": "test",
      "status": "Planned",
      "marker": {
        "symbol": "triangle",
        "radius": 7,
        "fillColor": "#3498db",
        "states": {
          "hover": {
            "fillColor": "#3498db"
          },
          "select": {
            "fillColor": "#3498db"
          }
        }
      }
    }, {
      "x": 1510203600000,
      "y": 0.25,
      "name": "Upgrade",
      "key": 159,
      "shortDesc": "test",
      "status": "Complete",
      "marker": {
        "symbol": "diamond",
        "radius": 7,
        "fillColor": "#2ecc71",
        "states": {
          "hover": {
            "fillColor": "#2ecc71"
          },
          "select": {
            "fillColor": "#2ecc71"
          }
        }
      }
    }],
    "color": "#1abc9c",
    "stickyTracking": false
  }, {
    "name": "Refresh",
    "data": [{
      "x": 1509336000000,
      "y": 1,
      "name": "Refresh",
      "key": 160,
      "shortDesc": "test",
      "status": "Late",
      "marker": {
        "symbol": "square",
        "radius": 7,
        "fillColor": "#e74c3c",
        "states": {
          "hover": {
            "fillColor": "#e74c3c"
          },
          "select": {
            "fillColor": "#e74c3c"
          }
        }
      }
    }],
    "color": "#036192",
    "stickyTracking": false
  }],
  "tooltip": {
    "followPointer": false,
    "followTouchMove": false,
    "shared": false,
    "backgroundColor": {
      "linearGradient": {
        "x1": 0,
        "y1": 0,
        "x2": 0,
        "y2": 1
      },
      "stops": [
        [0, "rgba(96, 96, 96, .8)"],
        [1, "rgba(16, 16, 16, .8)"]
      ]
    },
    "borderWidth": 0,
    "style": {
      "color": "#FFF"
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Points in a line series, by default, are being tracked in x dimension. You can change that by setting [series.findNearestPointBy](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.findNearestPointBy) option to `'xy'`.

> **findNearestPointBy**: *String*
>
> Determines whether the series should look for the nearest point in both dimensions or just the x-dimension when hovering the series. Defaults to 'xy' for scatter series and 'x' for most other series. If the data has duplicate x-values, it is recommended to set this to 'xy' to allow hovering over all points.

```
"plotOptions": {
  "series": {
     "findNearestPointBy": "xy",
     ...
  }
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/120pm1m7/